# how to prove the expectation of 1/x^2 when x is standard normal does not exist?

Tags: calculus, probability, integration

I am trying to show that the expectation of $\frac{1}{X^{2}}$ does not exist if $X$ is standard normal, but do not know how....could anyone help, please?
The integration is $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{X^{2}}e^{-\frac{X^2}{2}}dx$, and obviously the value of $\frac{1}{X^2}$ goes to infinity around $0$. So the integral should be improper, but how to state the logic?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a hint:  Show that on the interval $(0,1]$, $1/2 < e^{-x^2/2} < 1$, and consequently, $$0 < \frac{1}{2x^2} < \frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{x^2}.$$  Since the integrand $e^{-x^2/2}/x^2 > 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$, we can establish the inequalities $$\mathrm{E}[X^{-2}] > \int_{x=0}^1 \frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{x^2} \, dx > \int_{x=0}^1 \frac{1}{2x^2} \, dx.$$  What is your conclusion?

Comment: did it! thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Prove that the expectation is divergent. A necessary condition for the existence of $E(X)$ is the $\int |x|f(x)dx$ has to be convergent.